# Removal of subset of values from a hashmap in java

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Hi I've a Map variable defined as follow:

```
Map<String,List<Event>> myMap = new HashMap<String,List<Event>>();
```

Lets say the (key:value) pairs are (abc:(x1,x2,x3)), (pqr:(x2,x4,x5)) and (xyz:(x4,x2,x9)).

Now, to remove we would be doing myMap.remove("pqr"), but that would remove the whole (key:value) pair set.
But what I want is to just remove x5 in the set(x2,x4,x5) so that it leads to (pqr:(x2,x4)).

Please help me out in achieving this by suggesting some efficient ways to do so.

Comment: The definition of myMap is not being shown correctly in the question even after entering it correctly. It is basically Map<String,List<Event>> where Event can be assumed as a general object.

Comment: Can an event be in more than one list? Meaning, would I ever be able to find, say, `x5` in `abc` as well as `pqr`?

Comment: Sorry Todd, I didn't get your point. Anyway, here all the events are independent and have nothing to do with events corresponding to the other keys.

Comment: OK, if each `Event` can only be under one key, @JeanLogeart's answer works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
myMap.get(pqr).remove(x5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the values to be ArrayList, you'll have to get the value of the key "pqr" and remove the data from the arraylist as answered above.

Answer (score 0):

myMap.put(key, value) will update the key, value pairing (and return the original value), so I would suggest just putting the new values you want in the map.

Comment: thanks, but I would appreciate if you suggest a way to delete the event directly instead of the less efficient way of overwriting with the modified set(which can be very big at times !).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can really do this (meaning config restrictions) but it seems that you have some kind of `MultiMap` requirements.

I would suggest (if you can) to take a look on some MultiMap implementations, for example Guava. See related [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) or [here](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of your full specs and reqs, but in order to decide on the structure used to store Events, you have to consider if duplicates or/and ordering are a requirement too.

Regarding efficiency, due to the fact that you need to search for an Object (to remove it), I would go with a

```
Map<String, Set<Event>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Event>>();
```

or `Multimap` from Guava.

If ordering is not of your concern, use `HashSet<Event>` O(1) on add/remove

If natural ordering is required, use a `TreeSet<Event>` O(logn) on add/remove

If insertion ordering is required, use a `LinkedHashSet<Event>` O(1) on add/remove

Note: If you accept duplicates (which would be a good reason for choosing a `List` over a `Set`) the `myMap.get(pqr).remove(x5);` would only remove the first occurence of this object. If you need to remove every occurence of `x5`, then the following will work:

```
myMap.get(pqr).removeAll(Collections.singleton(x5));
```